# Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I have little problem with my code ;/ 
I want to create bot that send random meme from a folder but every time when i try to send it I got error with Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

This is my code (if u find any thing that will help in that code I will be glad to hear it!)

```
    const config = require("./config.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg')
const YTDL = require('ytdl-core');
const opusscript = require('opusscript');
const {get} = require("snekfetch");

const mem = ['./mem/']

const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});


bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log("Bąbelek jest gotowy!");

    try {
        link = await bot.generateInvite(["ADMINISTRATOR"]);
        console.log(link);
    }catch(e) {
        console.log(e.stack);
    }
})

bot.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    command = messageArray[0];
    args = messageArray.slice(1);

    if(command === `siwy`) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription("Siwy kocha Basie!")
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }

  if(command === `Siwy`) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription("Siwy kocha Basie!")
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
        message.channel.send(embed);
  }

    if(command === `basia`){
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription("Basia kocha Siwego!")
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }

  if(command === `Basia`){
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription("Basia kocha Siwego!")
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
        message.channel.send(embed);
  }

  if(command === `Arkes`) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setDescription("Arkes jest przyjaznym kitku!")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }

  if(command === `arkes`) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setDescription("Arkes jest przyjaznym kitku!")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }

  if(command === `Daniel`) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setDescription("Daniel jest bratem Siwego!")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
      .addField("I!", "Przyjacielem Basi i Arkesa!")
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }

  if(command === `daniel`) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setDescription("Daniel jest bratem Siwego!")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
      .addField("I!", "Przyjacielem Basi i Arkesa!")
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }

  if(command === `Dallader`) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setDescription("Dallader jest bratem Siwego!")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
      .addField("I!", "Przyjacielem Basi i Arkesa!")
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }

  if(command === `dallader`) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Wszyscy wiedzą że....")
      .setDescription("Dallader jest bratem Siwego!")
      .setColor("#00ffc5")
      .addField("I!", "Przyjacielem Basi i Arkesa!")
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }

    if(command === `meme`){
        message.channel.send("Łap! :3");
        message.channel.send(new Discord.Attachment(mem[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]));
    }

});

bot.login(config.token);
```

And this is error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined at
>   ClientDataResolver.resolveFile
>   (C:\Users\mrcyn\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\ClientDataResolver.js:274:25)
>   at Promise.all.options.files.map.file
>   (C:\Users\mrcyn\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:154:30)
>   at Array.map () at TextChannel.send
>   (C:\Users\mrcyn\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:153:40)
>   at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\mrcyn\Desktop\Bot\bot.js:123:19) at
>   Client.emit (events.js:182:13) at MessageCreateHandler.handle
>   (C:\Users\mrcyn\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
>   at WebSocketPacketManager.handle
>   (C:\Users\mrcyn\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
>   at WebSocketConnection.onPacket
>   (C:\Users\mrcyn\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
>   at WebSocketConnection.onMessage
>   (C:\Users\mrcyn\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)

Thanks guys for help!

Comment: What is `mem[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]` supposed to do? As far as i can see, as you declared it as `const mem = ['./mem/']`, it will end up with `undefined` in 6 of 7 cases

Comment: I wanted that bot will choose randomly meme and i thought thats gonna work

Comment: It would if `mem` would have seven entries pointing to files, not folders.

Comment: Soo how should it look?

Comment: probably something like `const mem = ['./mem/file1', './mem/file2', './mem/file3' ....]` up to 7

Comment: if you want to improve readability you can start with  `let command = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();` and then for your `if` statements just use the lowercase version. It will save you a lot of repeating code.

Comment: But I wanted to make that bot will pick random file from a folder without ['./mem/file1.jpg', ./mem/file2.jpg']

Comment: And what about this 'pipe' over there?